# Как вернуть пустую строку как True

Tags: java

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   
}
```

}

Comment: if (true) { return "";}

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Вы имели ввиду "Вернуть true, если строка пустая"?

Comment: откуда вернуть? из метода? из выражения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте [isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty())

```
if(string.isEmpty()) { // если строка пустая
    return "True";
}
```

Comment: @Alex Rudenko ему надо что бы `String` возвращал, и `true` было с большой буквы